# SQL Error: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Tags: sql, oracle

Please help me find out what I'm doing wrong here:

Error starting at line : 1 in command -

```
CREATE VIEW VW_ROUTE AS
  SELECT ROUTE_NAME
       , FARE
       , DESTINATION
       , ROUTE_ID
       , STOP_NAME
       , TERMINUS
       , NUMBER_OF_STOPS
  FROM STOPS S
    LEFT JOIN ROUTE R
        ON S.ROUTE_ID = R.ROUTE_ID
 WHERE NUMBER_OF_STOPS > ('1')
```

> ```
> Error at Command Line : 5 Column : 10
> Error report -
> SQL Error: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
> 00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"
> *Cause:    
> *Action:
> ```

Comment: Post the table schemas that you are joining. I assume you reference a column that exists in two tables and you need to use a table reference (alias).

Answer (score 5):

You have the same column name in both table. Add aliases.

```
CREATE VIEW VW_ROUTE AS
SELECT ROUTE_NAME
       , FARE
       , DESTINATION
       , S.ROUTE_ID          -- ROUTE_ID exists in table STOPS/ROUTE
       , STOP_NAME
       , TERMINUS
       , NUMBER_OF_STOPS
FROM STOPS S
LEFT JOIN ROUTE R
  ON S.ROUTE_ID = R.ROUTE_ID
WHERE NUMBER_OF_STOPS > ('1');
```

The good practice is to use aliases in all occurences to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: +eleventy-million for the statement "use aliases in all occurrences to avoid ambiguity"!